# Python: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code to download a web page in Python using Selenium and Firefox. A part of the page is rendered with Javascript, so I want to wait until a phrase is rendered.

This is the code I am using:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def firefoxget(url: str, file: str):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)
    
    WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'In Stock')]"))

    f = open(file, "w")
    f.write(browser.page_source)
    f.close()

    browser.close()
```

The problem is I get "find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 6 were given" at the `WebDriverWait` line. I am new to python, and unfortunately, it does not make sense to me since I cannot understand where 6 arguments come from.

Comment: They probably come from something in the path of code called indirectly from here. It's hard to tell, though, because you haven't [shown a complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) which would provide that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'In Stock')]"))
```

try this :

```
WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'In Stock')]")))
```

basically you are missing an open and close parenthesis. see near `By.XPATH`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used for `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'In Stock')]")` is wrong.

The syntax is:

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(locator, text)
```

> An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified element. locator, text

But I see no text value you are expecting to see in that element.
Maybe you just want to wait until this element becomes visible?
If so you should use `visibility_of_element_located` expected condition.
In you case:

```py
WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'In Stock')]"))
```

Comment: I tried changing the line as you suggested, but now I get ```__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given```, and I am still not sure where the extra argument is.